# Use JSON to show content from database

Tags: json, angularjs

On my website users can use a inputfield to insert the title of a movie into the database. Now I want to show that title on the frontpage of the website.

I have made template for showing it,

```
%div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies"}
  {{ movie.title }}
```

This is the controller,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .controller('movieOverviewCtrl', [
    '$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.movies = [
        {
          title: 'Star Wars'
        }
      ]

    }
  ]);
```

And now the title `Star Wars` is shown on the frontpage. But I can't figure out how to combine this with my `movies.json` file, which shows the values from the database.

I think I need to create a service and inject that service into the `movieOverCtrl` but I can't find a propper example for it.

Comment: How do you retrieve data from your DB?

Answer (score 1):

Use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to get data. Assign it to your scope property on success. Angular will do the rest.

```
function getMovies () {
  $http.get('/movies')
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.movies = response.movies;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a service which retrieve your json file using `$http` service. Then you can inject that service to your controller to use your movie data in your views.

Check out the example:

```
var app = angular.module('addMovieseat');
app.factory("movieService", function("$http") {
  var movieService = {
    retrieveMovies: function() {
      return $http.get("your-movie-file.json"); // return promise to your json file
    }
  };
  return movieService;
});
app.controller('movieOverviewCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$log', 'movieService'
  function($scope, $log, movieService) {
    function initCtrl() {
      movieService.retrieveMovies().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.movies = data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // log error
      });
    }
    initCtrl();
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I'm getting a `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: moviesProvider <- movies <- addMovieCtrl` error though. I'm not sure what `moviesProvider` refers too.

Comment: I forgot to call initCtrl function, I added that now. That error happens when you try to inject a service or data named `movies` into some controller or another service. Angular retrieves you services through providers. So when we declare a service named movieService, it creates that service by using movieServiceProvider. It appends Provider to service name automatically and it uses that provider to provide our singleton services (These are handle internally by angular).

Comment: The error I posted before was something I commented out, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I rememberd I did something like this on the Codecademy AngularJs tutorial.

The controller,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .controller('movieOverviewCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'movieService', function($scope, movieService) {

      movieService.success(function(data) {
        $scope.movies = data;
      });
    }
  ]);
```

And the serice,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('movieService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('movies.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        return err;
      });
  }])
```